# PHP Array cURL foreach

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I have again a problem, I want to use in ShoutCast2 the API and have an array a problem.

```
$sc_host = 'IP';
$sc_port = 'PORT';
$sc_user = 'USER';
$sc_pass = 'PASSWORD';
mt_srand((double) microtime() * 1000000);
$seq  = mt_rand(1, 100);
$post = 'op=listevents&seq=' . $seq;
$ch   = curl_init($sc_host . '/api');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $sc_port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $sc_user . ':' . $sc_pass);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$curl = curl_exec($ch);
$xml  = new SimpleXMLElement(utf8_encode($curl));
curl_close($ch);
```

Array Output:

```
Array (
    [@attributes] => Array (
        [seq] => 128
    )
    [data] => Array (
        [eventlist] => Array (
            [event] => Array (
                [@attributes] => Array (
                    [type] => relay
                )
                [relay] => Array (
                    [@attributes] => Array (
                        [priority] => 1
                        [url] => IP:PORT
                    )
                )
                [active] => 1
                [id] => 1
                [calendar] => Array (
                    [@attributes] => Array (
                        [starttime] => 00:00:00
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Now I want to read the output via array:

```
foreach ($xml->data->eventlist->event as $event ) {

        echo $event ->type;


    }
```

no issue is why? where is the error?

Thank you

EDIT ORIGINAL XML

```
<eventlist>
 <event type="playlist|dj|relay">
   <active/>
   <id/>
   <dj/>
   <playlist loopatend="1|0" shuffle="1|0" priority="#">
     nameofplaylist
   </playlist>
   <relay url=""/>
   <calendar/>
 </event>
 <event ... />
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing the SimpleXML element will not help you.  The data in there is *internal* to the class.

You just want to simply do this:

```
foreach($xml->event as $event){
    echo (string)$event['type'];
}
```

Comment: What do you see if you do `var_dump($event);` inside this loop?

Comment: I get back a dump `object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (5) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "relay"
  }
  ["relay"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["priority"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["url"]=>
      string(18) "IP:PORT"
    }
  }
  ["active"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["calendar"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["starttime"]=>
      string(8) "00:00:00"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Thanks got it hinbekommen through your help :)

Comment: Or maybe not ..... `foreach($xml->data->eventlist->event as $event){
    echo (string)$event['type'];
 echo (string)$event['url'];

}`  type it outputs, the url but not

Comment: Why are you looping over `$xml->data->eventlist->event` and not `$xml->event`?  Also, according to your XML, the `<event>` element doesn't have a `url` attribute.  It's on the `<relay>` element.  `echo (string)$event->relay['url'];`.

Comment: because otherwise I get no output

Comment: Did `echo (string)$event->relay['url'];` work for you?

Comment: It's funny ... I get everything now but unfortunately did not read active and id `echo  (string)$event->relay['active']; echo  (string)$event->relay['id'];`